# how to calculate leave based on leave duration in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the Leave function. Can somebody tell me how can I calculate leave based on leave duration?

```
def Leave(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        Leave = request.POST['reason']
        fromdate = request.POST['fromdate']
        todate = request.POST['todate']

        #fromdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(fromdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
        #todate = datetime.datetime.strptime(todate, '%Y-%m-%d')

        e = Employee.objects.get(user = request.user)
        print e.code, 'code of employee'

        lh = LeaveHistory()
        lh.reason = Leave
        lh.from_date = fromdate
        lh.to_date = todate
        lh.employee = e
        lh.num_of_days = ''
        lh.approval_status = 'p'
        lh.save()
```

Comment: Could you please clarify, what you mean by "calculate leave", does the refer to leave balance ? The questions is not clear

Comment: If you're looking for total number of hours or days taken as leave your commented code is on the right track.  You can subtract `todate - fromdate`.  But it's not clear what you mean by calculate leave based on leave duration.

Comment: i want to calculate number of days of leave based on leave asked from starting date of leave(i.e fromdate) to end date of leave(i.e todate)

Comment: but will subtracting todate - fromdate give me the difference?
do i need to use timedelta for that???

Comment: Yes to first question, no to second.  Use timedelta if you want to add or subtract say 8 hours from a datetime. You can subtract two datetimes, but not add (since that doesn't make sense)

Comment: okay okay understood...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just datetime subtraction:

```
fromdate = '2015-06-08 17:00:00'
todate = '2015-06-23 17:00:00'
dt = datetime.strptime(todate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(fromdate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print dt
```

prints:

```
15 days, 0:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`tdelta = datetime.strptime(todate, FMT) - datetime.strptime(fromdate, FMT)`

Comment: It shows "global name 'FMT' is not defined" error,
but anyways thanks, the problem is solved....

Comment: FMT is the format for time like "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"...you can choose whichever you want